# Error inserting an email string in sqlite3 and python Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, syntax, syntax-error

I am writing a simple program to update a basic db based on data entered on a simple GUI. I'm using string formatting but keep getting an error trying to enter an email address , which I know should be surrounded with double-quotes. I'm sure the solution is simple- I just don't know what it is!

```
def update_rec():
# Connect to the db
conn = sqlite3.connect("address_book.db")
# create a cursor
c = conn.cursor()
fields = ["f_name", "s_name", "mob", "email"]

# Check which textboxes have data
update_txt = ""
update_field = ""
rec_no = str(id_no.get())

if len(f_name.get()) > 0:
    update_txt = f_name.get()
    update_field = fields[0]
elif len(s_name.get()) > 0:
    update_txt = s_name.get()
    update_field = fields[1]
elif len(mob.get()) > 0:
    update_txt = mob.get()
    update_field = fields[2]
elif len(email.get()) > 0:
    update_txt = email.get()
    update_field = fields[3]
else:
    update_txt = ""
    update_field = ""

c.execute("""UPDATE address_book SET  {0} = ?  WHERE {1} = ?""".format(update_field, update_txt), rec_no)

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

I keep getting this error:

c.execute("""UPDATE address_book SET  {0} = ?  WHERE {1} = ?""".format(update_field, update_txt), rec_no)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "@gmail": syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What needs to be supplied to `.format()` is getting confused with what needs to be passed to `c.execute()`.

Do it in two steps so it's easier to understand.

You need to tell us what `rec_field` should be. It's probably something like `id` or `address_book_id` or ?

```
rec_field = 'id' # you know what this should be...
qry = """UPDATE address_book 
         SET {0} = ? 
         WHERE {1} = ?;""".format(update_field, rec_field)
c.execute(qry, (update_txt,rec_no))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply- I can see that this is clearer but how does it solve the entry of an email address string which is what I think the problem is? I want to set the email field(if data has been entered) to the value entered where the record number equals the one entered on the GUI.

Comment: You're welcome. The problem is two-fold. You're currently putting the email string in the wrong place in the query string, and you're not putting it in the place of the first placeholder where it should be. The sqlite3 library handles the quoting of the email string just fine so make sure you let it do its job.

Comment: Thanks again- I understand where I was going wrong now with the .format and query fields. I ended up doing it like this as I understand it better:c.execute("""UPDATE address_book SET  {0} = ?  WHERE oid = ?;""".format(update_field), (update_txt, rec_no))